# Remove WPF Back/Forward Page navigation Button in Desktop App

Tags: wpf, button, navigation, back

I am working on a WPF desktop application and I have a main window and I use frame control to navigate to different pages. It works perfectly fine. But I Want the Back/ Forward to be removed. How do I do it ? Please help me in this regard !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set **`NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"`** on your Frame object to hide navigation buttons.

```
<Frame NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"/>
```